# Calling a Workflow Foundation Service

Tags: service, workflow-foundation

I am a bit confused. Just playing around a bit with WF and trying to create a simple service like shown in this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/ff859495

In this example he creates a real simple service and calls it from the client like this:

```
var proxy = new ServiceReference1.MathClient();
var data = proxy.AddNumbers();
```

Now I did exactly the same, but I never ever get a class `MathClient`, all I get is an interface, a class for the receive part, a class for the send part and a namespace for the activities. But nothing where I actually can call the receive part.

The service itself is simple, just a `SendAndReceiveReply` that adds two numbers. The settings are done like in the video: Changed the `OperationName`, changed the `ServiceContractName` and set `CanCreateInstance` to `true`.

Where is the class actually coming from? He never creates anything called `MathClient`!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it, simple solution:

I've added a WorkflowConsoleApplication to call the service, but then you seem only to be able to use the workflow from the service as an activiy. If you create a normale console application, then you have the class for the service.

Comment: This is because Visual Studio creates a different proxy when the project is from a Workflow Template.  In the video I create a standard console app to consume the service.